# How to extract the first dimension in TimeSeries?

Tags: list-manipulation, time-series

I want to extract the first dimension in `TimeSeries`，for example:

[image]

So I use this code:

```
data = Normal@AudioLocalMeasurements[ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}],"MFCC"]; 
Thread[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, {1}]]}]
```

But it is a little complex,I want to know if there is more gentle way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `TimeSeriesMap` or `MapAt`:

```
audio = AudioLocalMeasurements[ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}],"MFCC"];

res0 = TimeSeriesMap[{First@#}&, audio]["Path"];
res1 = MapAt[{First@#}&, audio["Path"],{{All,2}}];
res0 == res1 == res
```

> True

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `"Properties"` specification of a `TimeSeries`, as introduced in the *Details* section of its [reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html). This avoids normalizing it.

For instance, with the properties `"Times"` and `"Values"`:

```
audio = AudioLocalMeasurements[ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}], "MFCC"];

res = Transpose[{audio["Times"], audio["Values"][[All, {1}]]}];
```

The symbol `res` gives the expected output:

```
data = Normal@audio;
res === Thread[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, {1}]]}]
(* True *)
```

Alternatively, you can use the property `"Path"`. Here is a possible way:

```
resBis = {#1, {#2[[1]]}} & @@@ audio["Path"];
resBis === res
(* True *)
```

Note that other objects of the language accept the `"Properties"` specification, once they are constructed through evaluation. These include `SparseArray` and `QuantityArray`:

```
spa = SparseArray[Range[10]];
spa["Properties"]
(* {"AdjacencyLists", "Background", "ColumnIndices", "Density", "MatrixColumns", 
    "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray", "Properties", "RowPointers"} *)

qa = QuantityArray[Range[10], "Meters"];
qa["Properties"]
(* {"Data", "Properties", "Structure"} *)
```

The specification `"Methods"` can also be used for these two last:

```
spa["Methods"]
(* {"AdjacencyLists", "Background", "ColumnIndices", "Density", "MatrixColumns", 
    "MethodInformation", "Methods", "NonzeroPositions", "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray", 
    "Properties", "RowPointers"} *)

qa["Methods"]
(* {"Data", "MethodInformation", "Methods", "Properties", "Structure"} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The more elegant way:

```
In[15]:= ts = 
  AudioLocalMeasurements[ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}], "MFCC"];

In[21]:= first = ts["PathComponent", {1}];

In[25]:= data = Normal[ts];

In[26]:= Thread[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, {1}]]}] == (first[
   "Path"])

Out[26]= True
```

Or without creating vector values:

```
In[15]:= ts = 
  AudioLocalMeasurements[ExampleData[{"Audio", "PianoScale"}], "MFCC"];

In[27]:= first = ts["PathComponent", 1];

In[28]:= data = Normal[ts];

In[29]:= Thread[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2, 1]]}] == (first["Path"])

Out[29]= True
```

Comment: (Tip: If you set `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ExportMultipleCellsOptions -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}]`, then the pesky `In[]`/`Out[]` labels won't be copied. It will make it easier for others to test and use your code.)

Comment: what is PathComponent.I can not find it in doc

Comment: `td = TemporalData[Array[x, {10, 2}], {0}, ValueDimensions -> 2]; td["DeveloperProperties"]`